# I couldn't find a working Telegraf inline query project

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf

I want to make a telegram bot about algebra. I need to send code to http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*(7-3) after the expr part. I want to send numbers with inline query, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The [original example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/v4/docs/examples/inline-bot.js) uses context [object deconstruction](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/), which doesn't seem to work and spits out error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'assert' of undefined`

Here is the code without object deconstruction, which works for me (I've made it superfluously verbose for better understanding ):

```
bot.on('inline_query', async (ctx) => {


  const offset = parseInt(ctx.inlineQuery.offset) || 0;

  let items = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    items.push({ title: 'Item '+i, desc: 'item '+i+' desc', id: '0000'+i, moreinfo: 'More info about item'+i+', mucho importante information'})
  }

  let results = items.slice(offset, offset+10).map((item) => ({
    type: "article",
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    description: item.desc,
    input_message_content: {
      message_text: '*'+item.title+'*\n'+item.desc,
      parse_mode: 'Markdown'
    },
    reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [
          [{ text: 'More info', callback_data: 'moreinfo' }]
    ]},
    hide_url: true,
    url: 'http://www.domain.se/'+item.id,
  }));

  console.log('hello');

  let ourReturn = ctx.answerInlineQuery(results, {is_personal: true, next_offset: offset+results.length, cache_time: 10});

  return ourReturn;
});
```

Here is the [article](https://akhromieiev.com/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-inline_query-in-telegrafjs/) that helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple examples of Telegraf usage at https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/tree/develop/docs/examples

[Here](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/docs/examples/inline-bot.js) is an example of a bot utilizing an inline query

Comment: Dont work this " inline query" example. I tried

Comment: What didn't work for you... Please give us any detail to work with

Comment: The inline query code in the link did not work

Comment: Did you use the exact code in there? Or have you fixed it up with your own logic? Please edit  your message to show us the code you tried and the error you got so we can help in a specific way

Comment: I used the same code written there.  I also added my own bot token code